# Dynamical array as a class member

Tags: arrays, perl, class

There is a following class:

```
package MyClass;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new
{
    my $class = shift();
    my $self = {
        _class_array => []
};

    bless ($self, $class);
    return $self;
}
```

How can I set/get add values to this array?

I tried the following code:

```
sub AddDataType
{
    my $self = shift();
    my $new_element = shift();
    my @array = $self->{_class_array};

    print("Number of elements ".($self->{_class_array})."\n");
    push(@array, $new_element);
    $self->{_class_array} = @array;
    
    print("Element added. Number of elements ".($self->{_class_array})."\n");
}
```

The output is the following:

> Number of elements ARRAY(0x21bb4c)
>
> Element added. Number of types 2
>
> Number of elements 2
>
> Element added. Number of types 2
>
> Number of elements 2
>
> Element added. Number of types 2

Questions are:

1. What does that mean: `Number of elements ARRAY(0x21bb4c)`?
2. Why array length always stays `2`?

Comment: The `[]` is a reference to an array, so `$self->{_class_array}` is a reference too. to access the original array, you have to dereference it: `@{ $array_reference }`. The [`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) might be a good read. Assigning the arrayref to `@array` makes `@array` contain the reference, not point to the same array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an arrayref as an array. Try:

```
sub AddDataType {
    my ( $self, $new_element ) = @_;

    print "Number of elements " . scalar @{ $self->{_class_array} } . "\n"; 
    push @{ $self->{_class_array} }, $new_element;
    print "Element added. Number of elements " . scalar @{ $self->{_class_array} } . "\n";

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, your array class element is an array reference. Your method should look like this

```
sub AddDataType {
    my ($self, $new_element) = @_;
    my $array = $self->{_class_array};
    print "Number of elements " . scalar @$array . "\n";
    push @$array, $new_element;
    print "Element added. Number of elements " . scalar @$array . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You got good answers already. I just want to mention that [Moose traits](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aAttribute%3a%3aNative%3a%3aTrait%3a%3aArray) can really make this kind of attribute stuff simple/fun.

```
BEGIN {
    package MyClass;
    use Moose;
    has "data" =>
        traits  => ["Array"],
        is      => "ro",
        isa     => "ArrayRef[Str]",
        default => sub { [] },
        handles => {
            AddDataType => "push",
            DataCount   => "count",
            NoData      => "is_empty",
            AllData     => "elements",
        };
}

my $thingy = MyClass->new();
print "DOES HAS DATAS? ", $thingy->NoData ? "NOE" : "YES", $/;
$thingy->AddDataType("OHAI");
print "CAN HAS DATA? ", $thingy->NoData ? "NOE" : "YES", $/;
$thingy->AddDataType(qw/ ANUDDER CUPLA HERE / );
print "I HAZ DATAS: ", $thingy->DataCount, $/;
print "HERE DEY IS: ", join(", ", $thingy->AllData), $/;

__DATA__
DOES HAS DATAS? NOE
CAN HAS DATA? YES
I HAZ DATAS: 4
HERE DEY IS: OHAI, ANUDDER, CUPLA, HERE
```